# Complexity of computing the Tutte polynomial of multigraph when the Tutte polynomial of the underlying simple graph is known

Tags: graph-theory, polynomials

Let $G$ be multigraph with $l$ loops and $m$ multiple edges and $G'$ be the
underlying simple graph (loops and multiple edges removed).

Assume the Tutte polynomial of $G'$ is given.

> Q1 What is the complexity of computing the Tutte polynomial of $G$?

From the recurrence, loops are easy to deal with.

There is closed form for the "thickening" of $G'$ -- replacing
each edge by $k$ parallel edges.

This comes from the [multivariate Tutte polynomial](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503607).

Both polynomials equal the chromatic polynomial at $y=0$.